# how to get the all ascendants and descendants rows in sql with recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, recursion

i have the following table data in  ms sql server table name category

[image: table data and schema]

and the problem is that i want to get the data of grand parent,parent,siblings,child and sub child and self.

i hope you get my point , if need any more clarification from my requirement i can edit my question just put a comment below.

as far about my try i searched stackoverflow and i found a lot of examples of getting full hierarchical data using parent but don't find anything which is related to pass the child and get parent, sub child and self.

I am also open for the solution which provide me solution using `linq` because then i can take complete data in Category and can use linq their on .cs page.

***Edit :***
if i pass the `7` which is `heritage` `CategoryId` then the query should returns the following rows

[image: desired result in case category id 7 pass]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use a recusive "Common Table Expression", or CTE.  This allows you to build the structure of your hierarchy.  Below is an example, modified to match your structure, based on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

```
WITH CategoryStructured (ParentCategoryID, CategoryID, Description, Status, Level) 
AS 
( 
-- Anchor member definition 
SELECT c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID, c.Description, c.Status, 
0 AS Level 
FROM Category AS c 
WHERE c.ParentCategoryID=0 
UNION ALL 
-- Recursive member definition 
SELECT c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID, c.Description, c.Status, 
Level + 1 
FROM Category AS c 

INNER JOIN CategoryStructured AS c_parent 
ON c.ParentCategoryID = c_parent.CategoryID 
) 
-- Statement that executes the CTE 
SELECT distinct cs.ParentCategoryID, cs.CategoryID, cs.Description, cs.Status, cs.Level 
FROM 
CategoryStructured cs, 


(SELECT level,ParentCategoryID,CategoryID from CategoryStructured WHERE (categoryID = 4) OR (level = 1 AND parentCategoryID = 4)) as thisCategory 


WHERE cs.level BETWEEN thisCategory.level - 1 AND thisCategory.level+1 
AND ((thisCategory.level != 0 AND cs.ParentCategoryID = thisCategory.ParentCategoryID) 
OR cs.categoryID = thisCategory.ParentCategoryID 
OR cs.ParentCategoryID = thisCategory.CategoryID 
OR cs.CategoryID = thisCategory.CategoryID)
```

Updated to reflect your updated question.

*edit* I know you were able to get the above basically working for you with the added distinct, but I thought of a better way to handle this after I left chat:

```
WITH CategoryStructured (ParentCategoryID, CategoryID, Description, Status, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID, c.Description, c.Status, 
        0 AS Level
    FROM Categories AS c
    WHERE 
     (c.ParentCategoryID IS NULL AND c.categoryID = 7) -- when 7 is a top level category, then it is the root level
     OR (c.categoryID = (SELECT c2.parentCategoryID FROM Categories c2 WHERE c2.categoryID = 7)) -- when 7 is some non-top level category, then 7's parent is the root
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT c.ParentCategoryID, c.CategoryID, c.Description, c.Status, 
        Level + 1
    FROM Categories AS c

    INNER JOIN CategoryStructured AS c_parent
        ON c.ParentCategoryID = c_parent.CategoryID
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT cs.ParentCategoryID, cs.CategoryID, cs.Description, cs.Status, cs.Level
FROM 
  CategoryStructured cs
WHERE cs.level < 3
ORDER BY cs.level
```

Comment: it will return only child,subchild but i want parent , siblings also

Comment: I don't understand - this returns the whole table, with each level identified.  What's the problem?

Comment: yah i checked it now sorry for previous comment i forgot about level now i have to query this table for my desired result

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like this answers your question.  Care to mark it approved?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6078/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-jake-feasel)

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect both the version we hashed out in chat that worked for you, as well as a version that I think will actually be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

the way i do it is, create a function and have it call itself for every level of the program, if your trying to output the data ud write out each level, or have it assembly some sort of array in the public scope, or static varible / singleton.

Its not pretty but recursion rarely ever is.

Comment: i am looking for some sort of cte in sql

Comment: im thinking u might be able to do it as a stored procedure? and keep calling the stored procedure from itself to handle the recursion.