# Query JSON for a given property without knowing the position of the property

Tags: json, sql-server

I have different JSON in my Database.

All with a different structure.

Example:

```
{
"DefinitionKey": "DocumentRelease",
"variables": {
    "isError": false,
    "ProcessItem": {
        "NamedValues": {
            "{|CompanyNumber|}": "90077"
        },
        "Department": null,
        "Tester": null,
        "ResponsibleAgents": "netCo.Demo\\CGiesen"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
"DefinitionKey": "DocumentRelease",
"{|CompanyNumber|}": "90077",
"variables": {
    "isError": false,
    "ProcessItem": {
        "NamedValues": {},
        "Department": null,
        "Tester": null,
        "ResponsibleAgents": "netCo.Demo\\CGiesen"
    }
}
```

}

Now I like to search for {|CompanyNumber|} so for example I would like to get all rows where CompanyNumber is perhaps 90077.

I know to query with `Json_Value`, but here I have to know the position in my JSON structure.

Newtonsoft.Json give me something like this

```
processInstanceExtendedVariables.SelectToken($"$..{pattern}");
```

Is there something similar in SQL Server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the all ascendants and descendants rows in sql with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612353/how-to-get-the-all-ascendants-and-descendants-rows-in-sql-with-recursion)

Answer (score 0):

Is your JSON consistent between the two examples, or are they all completely random?

If you have two different JSON structures you can use `JSON_VALUE` and `OR` in your WHERE clause.

You can run the example below in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @Data table ( id int, jsn nvarchar(MAX) );
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
    ( 1, '{"DefinitionKey": "DocumentRelease","variables": {"isError": false,"ProcessItem": {"NamedValues":{"{|CompanyNumber|}": "90077"},"Department": null,"Tester": null,"ResponsibleAgents": "netCo.Demo\\CGiesen"}}}' ),
    ( 2, '{"DefinitionKey": "DocumentRelease","{|CompanyNumber|}": "90077","variables":{"isError": false,"ProcessItem":{"NamedValues": {},"Department": null,"Tester": null,"ResponsibleAgents": "netCo.Demo\\CGiesen"}}}' );

SELECT
    jsn
FROM @Data
WHERE
    JSON_VALUE ( jsn, '$."{|CompanyNumber|}"' ) = '90077'
    OR
    JSON_VALUE ( jsn, '$.variables.ProcessItem.NamedValues."{|CompanyNumber|}"' ) = '90077';
```

Returns

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                       jsn                                                                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"DefinitionKey": "DocumentRelease","variables": {"isError": false,"ProcessItem": {"NamedValues":{"{|CompanyNumber|}": "90077"},"Department": null,"Tester": null,"ResponsibleAgents": "netCo.Demo\\CGiesen"}}} |
| {"DefinitionKey": "DocumentRelease","{|CompanyNumber|}": "90077","variables":{"isError": false,"ProcessItem":{"NamedValues": {},"Department": null,"Tester": null,"ResponsibleAgents": "netCo.Demo\\CGiesen"}}} |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**UPDATE:**

*"they all completely random..."*

In this case, I (personally) would resort to string parsing with an inline-table-valued function.

Here's the code I came up with for the inline TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValue (  
    @json nvarchar(MAX),
    @key  nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (

    SELECT
        REPLACE ( key_value, '"', '' ) AS key_value --strip double quotes.
    FROM (

        -- Get the initial part of @key's string
        SELECT SUBSTRING (
            @json,
            CHARINDEX ( @key, @json ) + LEN ( @key ),
            LEN ( @json )
        ) AS key_string

    ) AS x
    CROSS APPLY (

        -- Get @key's value from [key_string] (expects a quoted value)
        SELECT SUBSTRING (
            x.key_string,
            CHARINDEX ( '"', x.key_string),
            CHARINDEX ( '"', x.key_string, CHARINDEX ( '"', x.key_string ) + 1 ) - 1
        ) AS key_value

    ) AS n

);
```

You can call this inline TVF against my sample (updated) `@Data` table like so:

```
SELECT
    id, key_value
FROM @Data
OUTER APPLY dbo.GetValue( jsn, '"{|CompanyNumber|}":' ) AS x
WHERE
    key_value = '90077';
```

Which returns:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | key_value |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |     90077 |
|  2 |     90077 |
+----+-----------+
```

(excluded column `jsn` to conserve space)

Note that the key name is passed as `'"{|CompanyNumber|}":'`, the **full** key name, **including quotes and colon**.

The inline TVF I provided expects the return value of `@key` to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

they all completely random :(
And normaly I didn't know where the token could be find

The price of flexibility is hell sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You bring me to the right way. That's my solution now:

```
 CRAETE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetValue] (  
    @json nvarchar(MAX),
    @key  nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
-- Returns Value
BEGIN
RETURN 

REPLACE(
SUBSTRING (
           @json,
            CHARINDEX ( @key, @json ) + (LEN (@key ) + 3),
           (CHARINDEX ( ',', @json  , CHARINDEX ( @key, @json ) + (LEN ( @key ) + 3 ))) - ( CHARINDEX ( @key, @json ) + (LEN ( @key ) + 3))
           ),
           '"','');
END
```